# Append text from title attribute into each element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append the text from the title attribute into the `span` element. problem is that my `each function` doesn't work, so it add the same text to all elements.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div class="item topitem"
 <a href="#">
 <img src="#"></a>
 <a href="#" title="text to ad to span from first element" class="topdesc"><span>.                   
 </span></a>
</div>

<div class="item topitem"
 <a href="#">
 <img src="#"></a>
 <a href="#" title="text to ad to span from second element" class="topdesc"><span>.                   
 </span></a>
</div>
```

Script

```
$.each($('.topitem a.topdesc span'), function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<span style="text-align:center;">'+ (".item.topitem div a.topdesc ").attr('title')+'</span>');
})
```

Comment: `$('.topitem a.topdesc span').each(function() ...` and missing the $ here  - it also has a div too many: `$(".item.topitem a.topdesc ")`

Comment: and: `$('.topitem a.topdesc span').each(function() { $(this).text($(this).parent().attr('title')) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate on `.topitem a.topdesc` pick its title attribute and set it as html of the span inside it.

```js
$('.topitem a.topdesc').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).attr("title");
  $(this).find("span").html(title);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item topitem"
 <a href="#">
 <img src="#">
 </a>
 <a href="#" title="text to ad to span from first element" class="topdesc">
 <span>.                   
 </span></a>
</div>

<div class="item topitem"
 <a href="#">
 <img src="#"></a>
 <a href="#" title="text to ad to span from second element" class="topdesc">
 <span>.                   
 </span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: However the code would work if you had fixed the errors: `$('.topitem a.topdesc span').each(function()` ... and missing the $ here - it also has a div too many: `$(".item.topitem a.topdesc ")`

Comment: @mplungjan yea.. but it does not require replaceWith and all... this is way cleaner code..

Comment: @mplungjan yea... but I still I think `$('.topitem a.topdesc').each(` makes more sense..

Comment: `$('.topitem a.topdesc span').each(function() { $(this).text($(this).parent().attr('title')) );` :) - many ways

Comment: @mplungjan I agree.. :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is `$(".item.topitem div a.topdesc ").attr('title')`. This code will always target the first appearence of the element. You need to get the current target element title instead of like the above one. You can use the `closest` and get the current targeted element title like below.

```
$(this).closest("a.topdesc").attr('title')
```

```js
$.each($('.topitem a.topdesc span'), function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<span style="text-align:center;">' + $(this).closest("a.topdesc").attr('title') + '</span>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item topitem">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="#"></a>
  <a href="#" title="text to ad to span from first element" class="topdesc"><span>.                   
     </span></a>
</div>

<div class="item topitem">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="#"></a>
  <a href="#" title="text to ad to span from second element" class="topdesc"><span>.                   
     </span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is also not great `$.each($('.topitem a.topdesc span')` and why replacewith? And closest - why not parent?

Comment: @mplungjan I am giving the explanation to OP, because he want to know `what he did wrong`. I am just giving one way to resolve the issue. So you meant to say all the questions must have only one answer which is the great way. It should be many and the people can decide the best one and accept it or use it. For your question I can ask you again why jquery have closest and parent both??? If you really interested to give down vote, i won't stop it even i can't.

Comment: No I’m not. There are several things wrong also conceptual and you are not addressing those